# System Guard Runtime Monitor Broker Service Issues

Tags: windows-10, memory-management

I have Windows 10 and assumed that the System Guard Runtime Monitor Broker Service was there to help memory issues with Microsoft only applications.  I find it running even when I don't use Microsoft Applications like Microsoft Edge and it slows the computer to a crawl and I have to restart.

Is there anyway I can disable System Guard Runtime Monitor Broker Service in Windows 10 or make it so that it doesnt affect my performance so much that I have to restart the computer ?

What is the actual real reason for this System Guard Runtime Monitor Broker Service anyhow ?  Is it really managing the memory of Microsoft applications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Run Time Broker is normally silent and does its work behind the scene.

Faulty Apps can cause issues with Run Time Broker, and these apps need to be fixed and updated.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/runtime-broker-is-using-too-much-memory-ca6ed4e3-2a36-964c-4d2e-8c93980d8a98

If you are having issues, disabling Run Time Broker is not the solution.

For Windows (and not your own apps):

**(1) Try DISM and SFC**

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Restart and test.

**(2) If the above fails, run Windows 10 Repair Install**

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run Setup on the USB Key

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

Comment: Finally, in my experience, even though the Microsoft link says it is possible, in my experience you cannot stop the process from running in the task manager as this request is always denied.

Comment: Generally this is a process that should run and we need to look at what we have on our computer that might cause issues.  If you wish, in the Repair Install, you can Keep Data and then install software slowly and see it working well until you either fix it, or, see what has caused the issue.

Comment: This answer points to a different service than the question does.  (Runtime Broker deals with Microsoft Store apps, whereas SGRMBroker.exe deals with the sanity of system start-up.)

Comment: Strangely, sgrbroker was disabled on my (brand new) PC, and attempting to start it manually yields Error 1058: "The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled
or because it has no enabled devices associated with it." Any idea what that could mean?